# Windows shortcuts without a path

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, shortcut

'Regular' windows application shortcuts have a target which is a path to an executable file. This path is visible (and editable) in the shortcut's properties dialog.

But many shortcuts have no such path, only a (read only) application name is displayed. All the MS Office programs, for example, have such shortcuts.

How do these shortcuts work (I guess there's a progid involved), what are their advantages over 'regular' shortcuts and why would I want to use such shortcuts for my own applications?

Finally, can I create such a shortcut with an installer built by a Setup Project in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are "advertised" shortcuts provided by MSI.

Here's a google search that contains some information you might find useful:
[Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=advertised+msi+shortcuts)

I don't know if you can create these via a Setup Project.

Answer (score 2):

One advantage of advertised shortcuts is you can have certain features be installed on demand, and I think missing files can also be repaired if I'm not mistaken.  The downside as a user that I hate is I sometimes want to find out where the executable is and which executable is run and it's harder to find that out.

Answer (score -1):

Read MSDN, everything is detailed about Links.

Comment: Not a useful comment without some help pointing to the right section. especially as MSDN is so vast.